# How To Delete Mercurial Commits From The Beginning

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs

We have a huge repository which contains some very old commits that contain huge binary files. I would like to make the repo much more tiny, so I thought I could get rid of the first 200 commits. I saw `strip` removes all descendants, so it's not for this case.

What I'd like to achieve is like to ged rid of commits A and B, as if the repo's first commit would be C:

`[A]->[B]->[C]->[D]----------->[G]-[H]
                \              ^
                 \->[E]-[F]----|`

Is it common to do that (I never did :) ) and how would you achieve that?

Comment: Yes it's a duplicate, and the best solution from there is probably: `hg convert --config convert.hg.startrev=1234 <source-repository> <new-repository-name>`

Comment: But it is important to note the big caveat in the original answer: "Caveat: The new repo will have completely new changeset IDs, i.e. it is in no way related to the original repo. **After creating the new repo every developer has to clone the new repo and delete their clones from the original repo.**"

Comment: Yes that is true. Ironically that's what I'm just doing in this very moment :D

Answer (score 0):

[Histedit extension](https://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HisteditExtension) allow to remove only selected changesets